# How to use auth.phoneNumber in Firebase security rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

How to use `auth.phoneNumber` in Firebase security rules, like
`auth.phoneNumber == newDatat.phoneNumber`
or
`auth.provider == phoneNumber`

Comment: Please provide a bit of context and some example code of what you've tried so far.

Comment: It is funny that this question was answered in an official firebase youtube video and down voted here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLNJtnLIyPI

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [reference docs for the security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#authtoken):

> `auth.token`
>
> A variable containing the contents of the Firebase Auth ID token.
>
> The token contains some or all of the following keys:
>
> ...
>
> `phone_number`    The phone number associated with the account, if present.

So that should lead to `auth.token.phone_number`